# How can i change this code in a way that returns a string

Tags: c

How to change this code that function returns first n fibonacci numbers but in a new string,for example if n=10 output will be "11235813213456"

````
void sprintfFibonacciNumbers(int n)
{
    int f1 = 0, f2 = 1, i;

    if (n < 1)
        return;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", f2);
        int next = f1 + f2;
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    sprintfFibonacciNumbers(10);
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Create a string at the beginning of the function. Then, inside the loop, instead of printing the number `f2`, append/concatenate that number to your string. After the loop, return that string.

Comment: can you please help me with that, i lost too much time and i keep mistaking somewhere

Comment: @Aziz please could you help

Answer (score 1):

One way is to allocate a string on the heap and return a pointer to it.  Here's an updated version of your Fibonacci function:

```c
char* sprintfFibonacciNumbers(int n) 
{
    char str_buffer[50];
    char* fib_str = malloc(1000); //need bigger number if result > 1000 characters
    if (fib_str == NULL) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        exit(42);
    }

    int f1 = 0, f2 = 1, i;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
    {
        sprintf(str_buffer, "%d ", f2);  //converts f2 to a string
        strcat(fib_str, str_buffer);    //concatenates it to the result
        int next = f1 + f2;
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = next;
    }
    return fib_str;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```c
char* fib = sprintfFibonacciNumbers(10);
printf("%s\n", fib);
free(fib);  //prevent memory leak
```

**Edit** Here's the full code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* sprintfFibonacciNumbers(int n) 
{
    char str_buffer[50];
    char* fib_str = malloc(1000); //need bigger number if result > 1000 characters
    if (fib_str == NULL) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        exit(42);
    }

    int f1 = 0, f2 = 1, i;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
    {
        sprintf(str_buffer, "%d ", f2);  //converts f2 to a string
        strcat(fib_str, str_buffer);    //concatenates it to the result
        int next = f1 + f2;
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = next;
    }
    return fib_str;
}

int main(void) {

    char* fib = sprintfFibonacciNumbers(10);
    printf("%s\n", fib);
    free(fib);  //prevent memory leak

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesnt work in my code..not sure where is the mistake

Comment: @JuricaLakić What is it doing wrong?  It's working for me.

Comment: Not sure why, could you please paste full modified code because i really dont know where am i making mistake..thanks

Comment: I copy/pasted it and it shows as a result : -Xn11235813213455 :D.really dont know where i am mistaking...it needs to be  "11235813213456"